# Button not staying fixed when resizing window with the image

Tags: html, css

I have an image that gets resized/rescaled when I scale the window. I am now adding a button to it. I want the button's position to be fixed onto the image when I resize the window.

Maybe I am doing it completely wrong with the button. What is the right way to position the button that stays fixed to the image while resizing?

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #000028;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.button {
  position: fixed;
  left: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  height: 10%;
  width: 10%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1606228281437-dc226988dc3a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2070&q=80" />

<input type="image" class="button submit" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/95/200/300.jpg?hmac=XW2T1mpTuATtTLyDvkvdQqgh2nodO9Zudo3dH2aXCBA" alt="submit" />
```

Comment: Your volunteer helpers should not have to trawl through comments on several answers to glean your specifications. Put them in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a container `div` around the two elements. Give that container `div` a `position: relative;` and set it's `width` and `height`. Now they both will correspond to their parent and scale properly.

Remove the `style="left: 100vh"` from the button.
Remove the `bottom: 0;`

Give the img a width and height of 100%;

Change the `top: 0;` to `top: 50%;` and add `Translate-Y: (-50%);`

Also I would recommend to give the img the `object-fit: cover;` and `object-position: center;` so it doesn't stretch the image.

See how I did that in the code snippet.

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #000028;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}

.button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 10%;
  width: 10%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1606228281437-dc226988dc3a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2070&q=80" />

  <input type="image" class="button submit" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/95/200/300.jpg?hmac=XW2T1mpTuATtTLyDvkvdQqgh2nodO9Zudo3dH2aXCBA" alt="submit" />
  
</div>
```

Comment: Lovely solution! Exactly as I wanted. But one thing, the image is now zoomed in, it is not fit to screen I suppose?

Comment: I mean that's what you get by using images, they always are quite annoying to get responsive if you would like to get the exact ratio. So that's why I always use object-fit:cover; So it doesn't stretch out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `style="left: 100vh"`, `right: 0` and `top 0` from the button then your button will be fixed at top 0.

Now you can add `right: 20px` to keep button at the top-right corner.

Now since you need to keep it relative to image, just code the image with div and make the div `relative` since you image is 100% so it will cover entire with space.

Now make your button as `absolute` instead of `fixed`, it will move according to the image as required.

**Updated HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
  <img src="" />
  <input type="image" class="button submit" src="" alt="submit" style="" />
</div>
```

**Updated CSS:**

```
.box {
  position: relative;
}

img {
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.button {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 20px;
  height: 10%;
  width: 10%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
}
```

You can also add width and height to `.box` if you want to restrict image size.

Comment: then the button will be in the center right? I don't want it to be in center, rather right side like how I showed in the code above

Comment: You have added top 0 and bottom 0 which itself makes the button works odd. (Cannot hold these 2 values together as 0), what exact position you want your button at?

Comment: yeah exactly, I have not set the css right. How do I change it?

Comment: What exact position you want your button at?

Comment: 20px from the right side

Comment: Just add right 20px and remove bottom 0 or right 0. (top 0 and right 20 will make it to the extreme top-right corner.)

Comment: but that is top corner. I dont want the button to be at the top, it should be few pixels from bottom like how I showed in my example.

Comment: @Vika In your example, the button is centered on the Y-axis, and about 1/3 from the right. You said you had problems when resizing? Then absolute values like `20px` won't do you any good. How much (in percent) do you want the button to be from the right?

Comment: @ShubhamSarda the one you showed completely changes position when I resize the window.

Comment: @OskarGrosser as shown in my example, that is the position I need. It should stay there itself when I resize the window.

Comment: Okay so you need button to move according to the image then you just need to use Image as relative so your button will position itself according to the image.

Comment: yeah that is what I need. Sorry if I was not clear

Comment: How do I set the position relative then? Can you please edit the code?

Comment: You should copy the snippet down from the question to demonstrate your solution.

Answer (score 1):

While you *can* use the body element as a container, it would be simpler and more explicit to give your image and input their own container that's detached from the body's full height. Then you can position *absolutely* instead.

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #000028;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  /* needed for child element positioning */
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100vh;
}

.box img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.box .button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  /* shift the input up half its height */
  right: 20px;
  height: 10%;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1606228281437-dc226988dc3a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2070&q=80" />

  <input type="image" class="button submit" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/95/200/300.jpg?hmac=XW2T1mpTuATtTLyDvkvdQqgh2nodO9Zudo3dH2aXCBA" alt="submit" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this is great! But now I have to scroll the window because the image is large. Is it possible to make it fit to screen?

Comment: I'm not working on this any more until you update your question. We're all chasing a moving target here.

Comment: I have updated it.

Comment: Your update did not make your requirements any more clear. I see no mention of image sizing, 20px from the right, etc. You need to be _specific_.

Answer (score 0):

Because images cannot have children, I used a wrapper to contain the image and the button. With the wrapper having the same aspect-ratio as the image (`3/2`), and the image filling the wrapper fully (`width: 100%`, stretches along y-axis), we guarantee that the wrapper and image will always have the same undistorted size.

Now that we have a parent element of the size of the image, we can position the button relative to the parent (indirectly relative to the image, which is what we want).

Setting the maximum size to the viewport size, we guarantee that the image (wrapper) will always perfectly fit inside the viewport.

Example:

```css
/* Positioning */
#img-wrapper>.button {
  top: 50%;
  right: 10%;
  translate: 0 -50%;
}

/* Image wrapper */
#img-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  aspect-ratio: 3/2;
  margin-inline: auto;
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
#img-wrapper>.button {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  height: 10%;
}
#img-wrapper>img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

/* Styling */
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #000028;
}
```

```html
<div id="img-wrapper">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1606228281437-dc226988dc3a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2070&q=80">
  <input type="image" class="button" src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/95/200/300.jpg?hmac=XW2T1mpTuATtTLyDvkvdQqgh2nodO9Zudo3dH2aXCBA" alt="Submit">
</div>
```